# Is 192.056.2.01 a valid representation of an v4 IP?

Tags: networking, ip

I'm writing some code to convert an v4 IP stored in a string to a custom data type (a class with 4 integers in this case).

I was wondering if I should accept IPs like the one I put in the title or only IPs with no preceding zeros, let's see it with an example.

This two IPs represent the same to us (humans) and for example windows network configuration accepts them:

`192.56.2.1` and `192.056.2.01`

But I was wondering if the second one is actually correct or not.

I mean, according to the RFC is the second IP valid?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful, `inet_addr(3)` is one of Unix's standard API to translate a textual representation of IPv4 address into an internal representation, and it interprets `056` as an octal number:

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_addr.html

> All numbers supplied as parts in IPv4 dotted decimal notation may be decimal, octal, or hexadecimal, as specified in the ISO C standard (that is, a leading 0x or 0X implies hexadecimal; otherwise, a leading '0' implies octal; otherwise, the number is interpreted as decimal).

Its younger brothers like `inet_ntop(3)` and `getaddrinfo(3)` are all the same:

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_ntop.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html

### Summary

Although such textual representations of IP addresses like `192.056.2.01` **might be valid** on all platforms, different OS interpret them **differently**.

This would be enough reason for me to avoid such a way of textual representation.

Comment: Thanks, I was just going to autoanswer, I have found that inet_pton does not pass thos ips as valid, so i guessed I should do the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Pros**

In decimal numerotation *056* is equals to *56* so why not?

**Cons**

*0XX* format is commonly used to octal numerotation

Whatever your decisions just put it on your documentation and it will be ok :)

Comment: Thanks, what I wanted to know if is the RFC says anythong about this, I'm trying to find something in it with no luck so far.

Comment: RFC define protocols. The IPv4 protocol RFC only see IP adress as 4 byte. You are speaking about the representation of the IPv4 4 bytes. RFC don't care about it

Comment: @RaNdoM_PoWneD: RFCs “care about” *all sorts* of topics: see [RFC 3 - Documentation conventions](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3), [RFC 89 - Some historic moments in networking](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc89), and [RFC 149 - The Best Laid Plans](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc149), for example.

Answer (score 1):

[Textual Representation of IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-main-ipaddr-text-rep-02) is an “Internet-Draft”,
which, I guess, is like an RFC wanna-be. 
(Also, it expired a decade ago, on 2005-08-23,
and, apparently, has not been reissued,
so it’s not even close to being official.) 
Anyway, in [Section 2: History](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-main-ipaddr-text-rep-02#section-2) it says,

> The original IPv4 “dotted octet” format was never fully defined in any RFC,
> so it is necessary to look at usage,
> rather than merely find an authoritative definition,
> to determine what the effective syntax was. 
> The first mention of dotted octets in the RFC series is …
> four dot-separated parts, each of which consists of
> “three digits representing an integer value in the range 0 through 255”.
>
> A few months later, [[IPV4-NUMB](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc790)] …
> used dotted decimal format, zero-filling each encoded octet to three digits.
>                 ⋮
> Meanwhile,
> a very popular implementation of IP networking went off in its own direction. 
> 4.2BSD introduced a function `inet_aton()`, …
> [which] allowed octal and hexadecimal in addition to decimal,
> distinguishing these radices by using the C language syntax
> involving a prefix “0” or “0x”, and allowed the numbers to be arbitrarily long.
>
> The 4.2BSD `inet_aton()` has been widely copied and imitated,
> and so is a *de facto* standard
> for the textual representation of IPv4 addresses. 
> Nevertheless, these alternative syntaxes have now fallen out of use …
> [and] All the forms except for decimal octets are seen as non-standard
> (despite being quite widely interoperable) and undesirable.

So, even though [POSIX defines the behavior of `inet_addr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_addr.html)
to interpret leading zero as octal (and leading “0x” as hex),
it may be safest to avoid it.

---

P.S. [RFC 790](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc790) has been obsoleted by [RFC 1700](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1700),
which uses decimal numbers of one, two, or three digits,
without leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Defining if it is correct or not depends on your implementation.
As you mentioned windows OS considers it correct because it removes any leading zeros when it resolves the IP.

So if in your program you set an appropriate logic, e.g every subset of the IP stored in your 4 integer class, without the leading zeros, it will be correct for your case too.

Comment: Thanks, what I wanted to know if is the RFC says anythong about this, I'm trying to find something in it with no luck so far.